# Azure Function App proxy is removing the query string

Tags: azure, azure-function-app, azure-function-app-proxy

A simple, simple proxy redirect to our www subdomain is resulting in the query string being stripped off.

There is no reason for this.

Taken this URL..
https://mydomain.ok/whatever?foo=something

Should redirect to..
https://www.mydomain.ok/whatever?foo=something

Instead it currently redirects to..
https://www.mydomain.ok/whatever

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It's very hard to test this properly.

For the following, `REDIRECT_TO_WEBSITE=www.domain.com`

Here is the example configuration:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "api": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "route": "/api/{*path}"
      },
      "backendUri": "https://%WEBSITE_HOSTNAME%/api/{path}"
    },
    "rest": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "route": "{*rest}"
      },
      "responseOverrides": {
        "response.statusCode": "302",
        "response.headers.Location": "https://%REDIRECT_TO_WEBSITE%/{rest}",
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems just like a terrible bug or gap in the Azure specification. 

We had to create a "proxy endpoint" in the Function App in order to get this to work. If you are interested, I will post the code here as the answer (though it's more of a work around).

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer on another SO question: [Azure Function Proxies Multiple Query parameters with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73895743/azure-function-proxies-multiple-query-parameters-with-the-same-name)

You simply need to add the `request.querystring` to the `backend.request.querystring`:

```
"requestOverrides": {
    "backend.request.querystring": "request.querystring"
}
```

So, your config would be:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "api": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "route": "/api/{*path}"
      },
      "backendUri": "https://%WEBSITE_HOSTNAME%/api/{path}"
      "responseOverrides": {
        "backend.request.querystring": "request.querystring"
      },
    },
    "rest": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "route": "{*rest}"
      },
      "responseOverrides": {
        "response.statusCode": "302",
        "response.headers.Location": "https://%REDIRECT_TO_WEBSITE%/{rest}",
        "backend.request.querystring": "request.querystring"
      },
    }
  }
}
```

It's worth pointing out that according to a commenter on that thread: *"...going forward with .NET 6.0 onwards function proxies aren't supported, use API Management service instead"*

Comment: Thanks for the response! Not sure if I can test this. Proxies are being removed in the newer versions of Functions. :D