# Azure Function Proxies Multiple Query parameters with the same name

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

I have an endpoint that accepts request with multiple query parameters having same name like
domain.com/api/transactions?customerId=1&customerId=2&customerId=3

The challenged I face is I cannot seem to have function proxies to do this mappings for me. I am not sure if this is a capability function proxies do not have

```
  "matchCondition": {
    "methods": [ "GET" ],
    "route": "api/transactions"
  },
  "backendUri": "https://anotherdomain/api/transactions",
  "requestOverrides": {
    "backend.request.querystring.customerId": "request.querystring.customerId"
  }
```

I would like for the query parameters with the same name to be propergated to the backend. Any tip would be useful

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the issue was to force proxy to forward all request parameter  it receives like below:

```
"matchCondition": {
    "methods": [ "GET" ],
    "route": "api/transactions"
  },
  "backendUri": "https://anotherdomain/api/transactions",
  "requestOverrides": {
    "backend.request.querystring": "request.querystring"
  }
```

Comment: Note that going forward with .NET 6.0 onwards function proxies aren't supported, use API Management service instead.